# Get difference In minute of two dates

Tags: javascript, extjs

I Want to get difference in minutes of two dates, Meaning-

var diff= Current_Date- Date_Abc

and diff should in minutes.

What I want to do.
I have a GPS device And its get reporting every 30 second. If this device stop reporting from 90 minutes than I want to get stop flag for this.
In reporting information there is date Time "2017-06-21 12:55:21" in this format.
So I want to check If(CurrentDate-ReportedDateTime>=90) then DeviceStoped= true else DeviceStoped=false.
How do this in ext JS or in Java script

Comment: What have you tried so far? You sound like you know what to do, what has stopped you from doing this yourself?

Comment: Not going to give you a full on answer as this may require more questions from you but I highly recommend using MomentJS for all your datetime needs...the built in DateTime stuff in JS is horrible.  Take a look at this for examples of what you are looking for:  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: My doubt is about hot to compare difference with >=90

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are timestamps or instances of `Date`, you can try the following:

```
const ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60,
  diff = (currentDate - pastDate) / ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS;
```

So it's very straightforward, you can easily calculate the difference in milliseconds, then you just need to convert it to minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Get the milliseconds of both the dates and compare the difference with 90 minutes (5,400,000 ms).

```
var diffMs = (Date_Abc- Current_Date); // milliseconds between Date_Abc & 
Current_Date
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
```

To discard the seconds.

```
diffMins = Math.floor(diffMins)
```